# How can I trigger the select callback in FullCalendar for testing purposes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar, capybara

I'm trying to test the select callback of [FullCalendar](http://fullcalendar.io/) in Ruby on Rails app with Capybara (poltergeist as driver).

Any idea how to do this?

Comment: you're right! I thought this would omit the select callback but it only sets jsEvent parameter to undefined. if you post this as answer I can accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the select method

http://fullcalendar.io/docs/selection/select_method/

It will trigger the select callback.